# Can't rename files in Python

Tags: python, rename, batch-rename

I am going mad at this. I have a simple `cv2.imwrite()` command which save me only the images that follow a certain rule.

This is the code I am using to save:

```
cv2.imwrite(os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\output9\\causale-multi{}\\superiore\\box{}.png').format(file[0], i), roi)
```

And this is the folder I am obtaining:

[image: example]

What bother me is this: I can't rename the files in the folder to simple box0, box1, box2, etc.

I tried `os.rename`..

```
path = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\output9\\causale-multi{}\\superiore\\'.format(file[0]))
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(str(path)):
        for file in enumerate(files):
            if file.endswith(".png"):
                os.rename(file, os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\output9\\causale-multi{}\\superiore\\box{}.png'.format(file[0], file[0])))
```

...but gives error about tuple that have not attribute `.endswith`. I also used glob but nothing.

How can I simply rename these files ?

Pay attention that the folder `causale-multi{}` have a number in the end which change every time the code is executed.

Thanks

Comment: `for file in enumerate(files):` -> `for i, file in enumerate(files):`. Did you read the documentation on `enumerate`?

Comment: when you do `enumerate` you get a tuple, so do this `for index, file in enumerate(files)`

Answer (score 0):

`enumerate(files)` will iterate through `(0, file_0)`, `(1, file_1)`,...
just remove that unnecessary `enumerate`, or use something like:

```
for i, file_i in enumerate(files):
```

also don't use keyword `file` as variable name...

Comment: It doesn't work... A simplier way to rename that the one I posted above ?
I am using enumerate in other part of the code and it seems to work, it's just this. 
Gives tuple error like user1767754 said..

Comment: Yes and I gave you the same answer: use `for i, file_i in enumerate(files)`... this will remove the tuple error. (and of course use `file_i` everywhere instead of `file`)